# Django SMTP authentication best practices

Tags: django, smtp, postfix-mta, dkim, domainkeys

I have a Django website and a postfix service running in the same Ubuntu Server 10.04 box.

1. What type of authentication would you suggest me so that it'll be simple and secure?
2. If I want my messages to be DKIM/DomainKey signed and compliant with sender-id (so that they don't end up being marked as spam) what should I worry about?

Anybody?

Comment: are emails only going to be sent from your django app?

Comment: Yes, a Django app is going to send them

Answer (score 4):

There's a very good [explanation by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) about email authentication mechanisms.

Django itself doesn't support DKIM out of the box, but there is a [useful snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1995/) you could use to get started. It's a subclass of EmailBackend that automatically signs your message and includes the DKIM-Signature header.